# archive is not a ZIP archive in TOS for Bigdata(6.3 & 7.3)

Tags: talend

I have a zip file inside another zip file and when I extract the outer zip its extracting and when I am tried to extract the inner zip it is throwing me an error:
Error: Windows cannot open the folder
The compressed zip folder abc.zip is empty.
But it is working when I am extracting the inner zip file using 7zip in windows machine.

The same thing I'm trying it in TOD for bigdata in 6.3 and 7.3 the outer zip file is fine but while Im extracting the inner zip file I'm getting below error. Can somebody please suggest on this?

TOS(6.3)  Error:

```
Starting job Sample at 07:46 16/02/2021.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3356
[statistics] connected
Processing archive C:/Users/abc.zip, please wait...
Exception in component tFileUnarchive_2
java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.positionAtEndOfCentralDirectoryRecord(ZipFile.java:847)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.positionAtCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:777)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.populateFromCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:522)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:216)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:192)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
    at com.talend.compress.zip.Unzip.doUnzipWithoutDecryption(Unzip.java:191)
    at com.talend.compress.zip.Unzip.doUnzip(Unzip.java:76)
    at gannett.sample_0_1.Sample.tFileUnarchive_2Process(Sample.java:1230)
    at gannett.sample_0_1.Sample.runJobInTOS(Sample.java:2165)
    at gannett.sample_0_1.Sample.main(Sample.java:1350)
[statistics] disconnected
Job Sample ended at 07:46 16/02/2021. [exit code=1]
```

TOS 7.3 Error:

```
Starting job Sample at 08:00 16/02/2021.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3527
[statistics] connected
Processing archive C:/Users/abc.zip, please wait...
archive is not a ZIP archive
[statistics] disconnected
Job Sample ended at 08:00 16/02/2021. [exit code=0]
```

Comment: Please add appropriate tags e.g. `java` and add your non-working code.

Comment: Sorry I have added the tag and it is Talend